# How to align caption of minipage side-by-side with equation and image?

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, minipage

I have two side-by-side minipages, where the left is an equation and the right is an image.  I am trying to align the first line of the captions, but cannot find the right setting after checking the LaTeX documentation and searching this site.  The example is shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{minipage}[t]{.475\linewidth}
  \begin{align}
  x = 1 \\ y = 2 \\ z=3 \\ w=4
  \end{align}
  \caption{My equation.}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.475\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{\lipsum[34]}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: current output]

The desired output is shown below, where "Figure 1" and "Figure 2" are on the same line.  Is this setup possible? Using `[b]` for the minipages will align the last line of the captions, which is not the desired behavior.

[image: desired output]

Comment: Note it's rather unusual to have numbered equations in a figure, unless _all_ your equations are in figures, you will get figures appearing in the document out of numerical order.

Comment: The numbered equations in the figure are just a dummy.

Comment: One approach that appears to work is embedding the equation and graphics inside a `tikzpicture` environment.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use just four `\parbox` (or `{minipage}`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\parbox{.475\linewidth}{%
  \begin{align}
  x = 1 \\ y = 2 \\ z=3 \\ w=4
  \end{align}
}\hfill
\parbox{.475\linewidth}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\par
\parbox[t]{.475\linewidth}{\caption{My equation.}}\hfill
\parbox[t]{.475\linewidth}{\caption{\protect\lipsum[66]}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oh you just beat me by a second or two:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Got stung by a wasp this morning and it's been keeping me very fast, vigilant and active `:-)`

Comment: @campa For the first pair of \parbox that contain the equation and image, using \parbox[b] will align them along the bottom; is it possible to instead align the equation and image along the top? Using \parbox[t] causes the top of the equation to align with the bottom of the image.

Comment: @jII Yes, that's a bit trikier. `\parbox[t]{.475\linewidth}{\vskip0pt...}` should do. But maybe you need `\parbox[t]{.475\linewidth}{\vskip-\baselineskip...}` in the one containing `{align}` (can't test right now).